C++ function callback for class function
I have below snipped code works properly. But in my opinion it shouldn't work.
#include <functional>

template <class T> void run(std::function<void(T *)> fun, T *obj) { fun(obj); }

struct Foo {
  void bar() {}
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  std::function<void(Foo *)> fun = &Foo::bar;

  run(fun, &foo);                     // works
}


The bar() function is not compatible with the expected blueprint. bar() function accepts no parameter but std::functional accepts T *.
fun variable is defined only &Foo::bar. How compiler knows, it is function of foo object?


std::function supports assigning it with a class method, and then the invokation is with the class instance  - your T * obj, as if you did obj->bar(). You can see such example here - the one with f_add_display = &Foo::print_add.

For 2., member functions are not ordinary function pointers so a constructor of std::function can use CTAD to recognize them. In fact your use case is one of the reasons for using std::function because it just works nicely with all callables.

Unrelated, but always use lambdas, it will just make your life that much easier.

"bar() function accepts no parameter but std::functional accepts T *", yes but note that member functions implicitly have access to this. By design it's treated as the first argument when using pointer-to-member notation; I guess it's based on the fact that pointers to member are not bound with any specific object. But that's just what the language designers decided, e.g. Python operates completely different in that regard.

the answer is in constructor 5 here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function. Its just not easy to decipher because it is based on the Callable named requirement which in turn is based on the somewhat complicated INVOKE

"The bar() function is not compatible with the expected blueprint" - yes, it is. The explicit Foo* parameter in the blueprint is handled by the implicit this parameter of the bar method.
